# Why not define a "Dolbeaut complex" with $\partial$ instead of $\overline{\partial}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, complex-geometry

Yesterday I saw the definition of Dolbeaut cohomology: let $(M,J)$ be a complex manifold, write the exterior derivative as ${\rm d} = \partial +\overline{\partial}$, where $\partial: \Omega^{\ell,m}(M) \to \Omega^{\ell+1,m}(M)$ and $\overline{\partial}: \Omega^{\ell,m}(M) \to \Omega^{\ell,m+1}(M)$, look at the complex $$\cdots \xrightarrow{\hspace{.4cm}\overline{\partial}\hspace{.4cm}} \Omega^{\ell,m-1}(M)\xrightarrow{\hspace{.4cm}\overline{\partial}\hspace{.4cm}} \Omega^{\ell,m}(M) \xrightarrow{\hspace{.4cm}\overline{\partial}\hspace{.4cm}} \Omega^{\ell,m+1}(M)\xrightarrow{\hspace{.4cm}\overline{\partial}\hspace{.4cm}} \cdots$$and put $$H^{\ell,m}_{\rm Dolbeaut}(M) \doteq \frac{\ker(\overline{\partial}: \Omega^{\ell,m}(M) \to \Omega^{\ell,m+1}(M))}{{\rm Im}(\overline{\partial}: \Omega^{\ell,m-1}(M) \to \Omega^{\ell,m}(M))}.$$Great.

> **Question:** Why did we took the above complex instead of $$\cdots \xrightarrow{\hspace{.4cm}\partial\hspace{.4cm}} \Omega^{\ell-1,m}(M)\xrightarrow{\hspace{.4cm}\partial\hspace{.4cm}} \Omega^{\ell,m}(M) \xrightarrow{\hspace{.4cm}\partial\hspace{.4cm}} \Omega^{\ell+1,m}(M)\xrightarrow{\hspace{.4cm}\partial\hspace{.4cm}} \cdots?$$

I get that $f: M \to \Bbb C$ is $J$-holomorphic if and only if $\overline{\partial}f = 0$ so that $\overline{\partial}$ sort of measures how stuff in general would be away from being holomorphic. But I'd like a more solid explanation.

Comment: Note that $\bar\partial$ gives rise to well-defined cohomology for holomorphic vector bundles. If you want to switch to anti-holomorphic bundles on anti-complex manifolds, go ahead :)

Comment: Yes, people do consider that complex and its cohomology (when it is well-defined). To my knowledge, the reason why Dolbeaut's complex is mentioned more often is exactly your last paragraph and the above comment.

Comment: From a strictly pragmatical standpoint (from someone who knows nothing about Dolbeaut cohomology), when one computes things *using* (co)homology or *for* (co)homology, one frequently needs to get their hands on representatives of classes. Knowing that a representative will be a $J$-holomorphic mapping is an advantage, regardless of what it is measuring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both $\partial$ and $\bar{\partial}$ are well defined locally. However, when we are looking at a global section of a holomorphic vector bundle, then $\partial$ is in general not well defined! (When both are well-defined, indeed I have seen people who consider both complexes and cohomologies.)

The point is that to describe a section, we usually pass to local trivialization, and patch them together with transition functions. When the bundle is **holomorphic**, by definition there is an atlas such that the transition functions are **holomorphic**. So by product rule and that $\bar{\partial}f=0$ for any holomorphic $f$, $\bar{\partial}$ can be extended from local to global.

Usually people care about holomorphic bundles more (I wonder why). If you are dealing with anti-holomorphic bundles, then indeed $\partial$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

The differential $\partial$ depends on the trivialisation of your vector bundle but not $\overline \partial$, see lemma 2.33 page 58 in Voisin's book.